# Не могу проинициализировать родительские классы (проблема ромба)

Tags: c++, классы, множественное-наследование, виртуальная-функция

Я изучаю так называемую "проблему ромба, алмаза смерти".
При попытке проинициализировать родительские классы через дочерний, получаю ошибки:

error C2594: инициализация: неоднозначные преобразования "Frankenstein *" в "Animal *"

error C2243: приведение типов: преобразование "Frankenstein *" в "Animal *" существует, но недоступно

Код:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    std::string name;
    Animal(std::string n):name(n) {}
    ~Animal() {}
    virtual void sayName() { std::cout << "It's a basic function"; }
};

class Bird :public Animal
{
public:
    Bird(std::string n) :Animal(n) {}
    virtual void sayName() { std::cout << "Hello! I'm Bird. Ny name is: " << name; }
};

class Dog :public Animal
{
public:
    Dog(std::string n) :Animal(n) {}
    virtual void sayName() { std::cout << "Hello! I'm Dog. Ny name is: " << name; }
};

//создаю дочерний класс от дочерних классов, где родитель Animal
class Frankenstein :public Bird, Dog
{
public:
//уверен, что ошибка в инициализации родительский классов, но в чем именно?
    Frankenstein(std::string a, std::string b):Bird(a),Dog(b) {}
    virtual void sayName() { std::cout << "Hello! I'm frankenstein. Ny name is: " << Bird::name << " or " << Dog::name; }
};

int main() {
    Animal* ptr = new Frankenstein{ "Pirat", "Puffy" };
    ptr->sayName();
}
```

Comment: Проблема ромба обычно вызывается неправильно построенной иерархии классов. Нечего плодить франкенштейнов.

Comment: Наследуйте виртуально Dog и Bird. 
class Bird : virual public Animal

Comment: @afjord да,так безусловно работает, но хотелось бы своими глазами увидеть дублирование супер-класса.

Comment: Еще непонятно почему "*уверен, что ошибка в инициализации родительский классов*" - хотя компилятор прямо говорит, что ошибка в преобразовании указателя в `Animal *`. Для такого преобразования надо делать явный каст к одному из двух базовых классов. `Animal* ptr{static_cast< Bird * >(new Frankenstein{ "Pirat", "Puffy" });`

Comment: Тут  нет ромбовидного наследования, следовательно нет проблемы ромба. Каждый  Frankenstein  это  и  Dog и  Bird, которые  не просто животные _ они разные животные(построены на разных объектах).  Таким образом  Frankenstein имеет две базовые объекты  Animal.  Это тот случай, когда  базу нужно делать абстрактным и виртуальным(тогда получите ромбовидное наследование), потому что не "нарисовать" животного", пока не сказали какого.  Животное некое общее понятие, и иметь повторяющийся базовый класс не логично и может привести к путанице.

Answer (score -1):

Слегка подправил класс, чтобы увидеть вызов деструкторов, плюс main изменил `Animal` на `Frankenstein`. Чтобы не приводить типы, т.к. это в данном случае не критично.

```
class Animal
{
public:
    std::string name;

    Animal(const std::string &name) : name(name) {}

    virtual ~Animal() {
        std::cout << "Animal destructor\n";
    }
    virtual void sayName() { std::cout << "It's a basic function"; }
};

class Bird :public Animal
{
public:
    Bird(std::string n) :Animal(n) {}
    virtual void sayName() { std::cout << "Hello! I'm Bird. Ny name is: " << name; }
};

class Dog :public Animal
{
public:
    Dog(std::string n) :Animal(n) {}
    virtual void sayName() { std::cout << "Hello! I'm Dog. Ny name is: " << name; }
};

//создаю дочерний класс от дочерних классов, где родитель Animal
class Frankenstein :public Bird, Dog
{
public:
//уверен, что ошибка в инициализации родительский классов, но в чем именно?
    explicit Frankenstein(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) : Bird(b), Dog(a) {
}
    virtual void sayName() { std::cout << "Hello! I'm frankenstein. Ny name is: " << Bird::name << " or " << Dog::name << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    Frankenstein* ptr = new Frankenstein("Pirat", "Puffy");
    ptr->sayName();
    delete ptr;
}
```